# How to find changes in a field based on multiple conditions?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table with PolicyNumber, RoleCode, and SourceDate fields. I am trying to get a count of how many times a Policy had an owner change. I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2017. Some information about the table:
RoleCode of 8 =  owner.
If there is no record of a RoleCode of 8 for a PolicyNumber that is not considered to have an owner change and the count should be 0.
An owner change can be indicated in two ways:

1. If there are multiple records for a policy with a RoleCode of 8 then each instance of the 8 after the first instance is considered an owner change.
2. If there is an instance of RoleCode of 8 and the SourceDate for that instance is later than a record with an instance of RoleCode of 32, then that would also be considered an owner change.

Create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE PolicyTable (
PolicyNumber VARCHAR(10),
RoleCode INT,
SourceDate DATE
);

-- Insert data into the table
INSERT INTO PolicyTable (PolicyNumber, RoleCode, SourceDate)
VALUES
('660169245', 34, '2023-10-03'),
('660169245', 31, '2023-10-03'),
('660169245', 8, '2023-10-05'),
('660169245', 32, '2023-10-03'),
('660169243', 8, '2023-10-04'),
('660169243', 41, '2023-10-01'),
('660169243', 32, '2023-09-10'),
('660169243', 38, '2023-09-10'),
('660169243', 107, '2023-09-10'),
('660169243', 8, '2023-09-10'),
('660169243', 38, '2023-09-30'),
('660169243', 107, '2023-09-30'),
('660169243', 8, '2023-09-30'),
('660169238', 8, '2023-01-01'),
('660169238', 32, '2023-01-01'),
('660169238', 107, '2023-01-01'),
('660169238', 38, '2023-01-01'),
('660169236A', 107, '2023-05-31'),
('660169236A', 38, '2023-06-10'),
('660169236A', 8, '2023-06-10'),
('660169236A', 8, '2023-05-31'),
('660169236A', 32, '2023-05-15'),
('660169236A', 38, '2023-05-15'),
('660169236A', 8, '2023-05-15'),
('660169236A', 107, '2023-05-15'),
('660169236A', 32, '2023-05-31');
```

I was able to achieve the goal of the first condition above, but I'm struggling with how to achieve the second condition.

My Code:

```
WITH OwnerChangeCTE AS (
SELECT
    PolicyNumber,
    RoleCode,
    SourceDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyNumber ORDER BY SourceDate) AS RowNum
FROM
    PolicyTable
WHERE
    RoleCode = 8
)

SELECT
p.PolicyNumber,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE
    WHEN o1.RowNum = 1 THEN NULL
    WHEN o2.RoleCode = 32 AND o2.SourceDate < o1.SourceDate THEN NULL
    ELSE o1.RowNum
END) AS OwnerChanges
FROM PolicyTable p
LEFT JOIN OwnerChangeCTE o1
  ON p.PolicyNumber = o1.PolicyNumber
LEFT JOIN OwnerChangeCTE o2
  ON p.PolicyNumber = o2.PolicyNumber
  AND o1.RowNum < o2.RowNum
GROUP BY
  p.PolicyNumber
```

This code provides the output:

| PolicyNumber | OwnerChanges |
| --- | --- |
| 660169245 | 0 |
| 660169243 | 2 |
| 660169236A | 2 |
| 660169238 | 0 |

My expected output should be:

| PolicyNumber | OwnerChanges |
| --- | --- |
| 660169245 | 1 |
| 660169243 | 2 |
| 660169236A | 2 |
| 660169238 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

There may be more performant methods to get this done, but consider:

```
SELECT PolicyNumber, SUM(tick) AS OwnerChanges
  FROM (
         SELECT p.PolicyNumber, p.RoleCode, p.SourceDate, CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN RoleCode = 8 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY p.RoleCode ORDER BY p.SourceDate) > 1 
                                                                AND ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyNumber ORDER BY SourceDate) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS tick
           FROM @PolicyTable p
          WHERE p.RoleCode IN (8,32)
       ) a
 GROUP BY PolicyNumber
 ORDER BY CASE PolicyNumber WHEN '660169245' THEN 1 WHEN '660169243' THEN 2 WHEN '660169236A' THEN 3 ELSE 4 END;
```

| PolicyNumber | OwnerChanges |
| --- | --- |
| 660169245 | 1 |
| 660169243 | 2 |
| 660169236A | 2 |
| 660169238 | 0 |

Here we're just using a `CASE` expression with a pair of windowed functions which figure out if we should count the row, or not.
The `COUNT` determines if there has been a prior RoleCode of 8, and the `ROW_NUMBER()` determines if this is the first row or not.

Answer (score 0):

Single-scan query:

```
select PolicyNumber,sum(OwnershipRow) as OwnershipChangeCount
from 
(
  select PolicyNumber
  ,rn=row_number() over (partition by PolicyNumber order by SourceDate asc,RoleCode asc)
  ,OwnershipRow=case when RoleCode=8 then 1 else 0 end
  from PolicyTable
  where RoleCode in (8,32)
)t
where rn>1
group by PolicyNumber
```

My previous take was to make a FirstOwnerships table first, then count the rest:

```
select top 1 with ties PolicyNumber,SourceDate
into FirstOwnerships
from PolicyTable
where RoleCode in (8,32)
order by row_number() over (partition by PolicyNumber order by SourceDate asc)

select f.PolicyNumber,q1.OwnerChanges
from 
  FirstOwnerships f
  outer apply(select count(*) as OwnerChanges from PolicyTable p where p.PolicyNumber=f.PolicyNumber
and p.SourceDate>f.SourceDate and p.RoleCode=8) as q1
```